# In Dyno Heroku PostgreSQL is not reponding

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, heroku, heroku-ci

I've been using In Dyno Heroku PostgreSQL for a while, but for some reason, it has stopped responding a week ago. I haven't changed anything and even when running old commits it still doesn't respond. And by not responding I mean that when I am trying to connect a client to DB, nothing happens. No error message, no timeout, nothing. And as a result, I cannot run any test in Heroku CI. I am using pg-node to connect to DB. This is my code in app.json:

```
{
  "buildpacks": [
    { "url": "heroku/nodejs" }
  ],
  "environments": {
    "test": {
      "env": {  "POSTGRESQL_VERSION": "12" },
      "addons": ["heroku-postgresql:in-dyno", "heroku-redis:hobby-dev"]
    }
  }
}
```

And this is how I connect to DB:

```
client = new Client({
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL
})
client.connect()
.then(ob => {...}
.catch(err => {...}
```

It never enters `then` or `catch`. It's just being stuck forever.
Any idea why it stopped working out of the blue?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes what happens, a process in Postgres lock and prevent your app from working.
You first need to check whether any process preventing your app from working?

- For this run command `heroku pg:ps`.
- You will see a log output of the processes.
- From log output identify the stuck process
- After identifying kill that process using `heroku pg:kill 1234 -a example_app_name` where `1234` is the process id.
- If you are unable to identify the sticking process id then kill all the processes using
  `heroku pg:killall -a example_app_name`.
- After this, you should restart your app to remove any previous bad connections:
  `heroku restart -a example_app_name`

Comment: When I run heroku pg:ps -a my-app-name it returns me an error "my-app-name has no databases". I am using the In Dyno PostgreSQL only for CI. Maybe it wasn't clear.

Comment: You have to write your app name at the place of `my-app-name`. When we create an app on Heroku it has a unique name. Use that name at the place of `my-app-name`.

Comment: Yes, I did put my name at the place of my-app-name. The point is that the app does not user pg, the CI does.

Comment: No, it isn't. I cannot share my repo with you, I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

For some reason updating `pg` package helped.